# Where is my mistake - Date calculator for selectbox in Javascript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, drop-down-menu, leap-year

```
$(.dateselboxes) .change( function(){

var y; y=$("#year").val();
var m; m=$("#month").val();
var d;
```

// check leap year

```
var leapYear;
if(y%4==0)
{
    if(y%100==0)
    {
        if(y%400==0) {leapYear=true;}
        else {leapYear=false;}
    }
    else {leapYear=true;}
}
else {leapYear=false;}
```

// calculate the number of days

```
var dz;
if(m==1 || m=3 || m=5 || m=7 || m=8 || m=10 || m=12) {dz=31;}
else if(m==2)
    {
        if(leapYear==true) {dz=29;}
        else {dz=28;}
    }
else {dz=30;}
```

// remove last option a couple of times

```
switch(dz)
    {
        case 28:
            for(i=0;i<3;i++)
            {$("#day option:last").remove();}
            break;
        case 29:
            for(i=0;i<2;i++)
            {$("#day option:last").remove();}
            break;
        case 30:
            $("#day option:last").remove();
            break;
        default:
            var axaxax=0;
            break;
    }
```

});

Comment: can you specify what exactly is not working?

Answer (score 2):

Here you go, **this code works** (in Chrome, at least):

```
var opts = $('#day option').get();

$('#month, #year').change(function() {
    var y = +$('#year').val(),
        m = +$('#month').val(),
        leap = y % 400 === 0 || y % 100 !== 0 && y % 4 === 0 ? true : false,
        days = 30;

    switch ( m ) {
        case 1: case 3: case 5: case 7: case 8: case 10: case 12:
            days = 31; break;
        case 2: 
            days = leap ? 29 : 28; break; 
    }

    $('#day').empty().append( opts.slice(0, days) );

});
```

***Live demo:*** http://jsfiddle.net/83yUF/

Answer (score 1):

`$(.dateselboxes)`! This will not select anything, however `$(".dateselboxes")` will. The jQuery $ accepts a string as its argument representing the selector.

Asside from that your question has no explanation and loads of code, I haver no idea what is going on!

Answer (score 1):

Where you are calculating the number of days by checking the month #, you have single = instead of ==. 
Replace with:

```
if(m==1 || m==3 || m==5 || m==7 || m==8 || m==10 || m==12) {dz=31;}
```

The single = will assign the new value to your m variable and always evaluate to be true, so I assume you were seeing 31 in your day selector always.  As a practice, I like to avoid this scenario by reversing the check.  ie: `if(0 == x)` since you can't assign to 0 an accidental single = will result in a javascript error, making it easier to avoid the mistake.

Comment: thanks for the help, i did correct the mistakes, but still cant get this work

Comment: Did you correct the issue with your jQuery selector too?  If you're still having the problem, knowing what issue you're seeing and what your HTML DOM looks like will likely help get you a more definite answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with assigning (=) to variable m instead of comparing (==)

```
if(m==1 || m==3 || m==5 || m==7 || m==8 || m==10 || m==12) {dz=31;}
```

As a side note, you could rewrite some parts of your script.

leapYear var - this uses 2 statements to reduce it yet still keep it readable.

```
leapYear = (y%4==0);
if (leapYear && (y%100==0) && !(y%400==0))
    leapYear=false;
```

to remove the last options (0-indexed)

```
{$("#day option:gt(" + dz + ")").remove();}
```